# Android how to remove gps update icon from map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am using google map v2 and using this line of code to  enable my current location

```
 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

I am getting blue icon to my current location but i unable to hide the locator icon appear on right top of frame, i want to hide this one. Already i am showing filter icons there so this get disturb by locator icon.

Answer (score 8):

Try using

> map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this method: `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` and basically you are adding the you Google Maps API V2 the functionality that will allow it users to locate them selves by pressing this button in the upper-right corner.

you can disable and remove this button by simply setting it to false, but this will remove the functionality as well and you will have to develop it on your own using a `LocationListener`.